# Service is always null using lightinject

Tags: light-inject

I'm trying to register some services on a base controller that will available per request.

```
public interface IInstagramApiService
{
}

public interface IApiServiceConfiguration
{
    string CacheKeyPrefix { get; }
}
```

Then I have some concrete implementations of these

```
public class InstagramApiService : IInstagramApiService
{
   IApiServiceConfiguration ApiServiceConfiguration { get; set; }

   public InstagramApiService(IApiServiceConfiguration apiServiceConfiguration)
   {
       ApiServiceConfiguration = apiServiceConfiguration;
   }

}

public class ApiServiceConfiguration : IApiServiceConfiguration
{
    public string CacheKeyPrefix
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

Then I have base controller that I want to register this service too;

```
public class BaseController : Controller
{
    IInstagramApiService InstagramApiService { get; set; }        
}
```

So in my app start up I have this initialization;

```
var instagramApiServiceConfiguration = new ApiServiceConfiguration() { 
     CacheKeyPrefix = "The Cache Key Prefix",
};

container.Register<IInstagramApiService>((factory) => new InstagramApiService(instagramApiServiceConfiguration), new PerRequestLifeTime());
```

But when I check the `InstagramApiService` on the `BaseController` it's always `null`. What is the correct way to set this up so I will always have the `InstagramApiService` ready to use within my controllers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was missing a simple `public` modifier on my `InstagramApiService` inside the `BaseController`.

```
public class BaseController : Controller
{
    public IInstagramApiService InstagramApiService { get; set; }        
}
```